TV show with a main character who could turn into an orange creature
It was a show I used to watch a few years ago. I barely remember it, but I remember a main character who could turn into this furry orange creature that had a tail.
My guess is computer generated and 3D. I think it was around 2017-2018 but it’s all kind of a blur to me. I do remember the main character had black hair.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Was the show animated or live-action? If animated, was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)? Did the MC turn into a large creature or a small one? Roughly how old was the MC?

My guess is computer generated and It was 3d. I think It was around 2017-2018 but it’s all kind of a blur to me. I do remember the main character had black hair but it’s honestly such a blur to me it’s hard to say details

Was the MC male or female? And roughly how old were they?

If any extra details do come to mind please do [edit] them in. This list is often helpful if you need some help.

I’ll update it when I can it’s really hard to rnemebrt then but I’ll add what I can, my guess is the main character was 16-18 and they were male I also think their hair was spiked up I could be wrong

From what I remember the mc turned into a big orange cat looking thing that stood on two legs it was orange is the main thing I remember

Not Turning Red (2022)?

Nah it’s not I could be wrong but I had a feeling the name was z something
